# AndroidX project that depend on not AndroidX libraries

Tags: android, androidx

I have migrated to AndroidX and i facing problem with libraries that using old namespace.

For example some method that requires old FragmentManager shows

```
no suitable method found for show(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager,String)
```

How can i solve this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in `gradle.properties` file

this line is written

`android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: can you name the library?

Comment: https://github.com/heysupratim/MaterialDateRangePicker/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/borax12/materialdaterangepicker/date/DatePickerDialog.java

Comment: The problem is the show method is taking Android sdk fragmentManager. That's why it's not working. You have to pass Activity.getFragmentManager()